# Android set fixed GridView height in custom Keyboard

Tags: android, gridview, height

I'm making a custom Emoji keyboard for a client. We already have an iOS app and now trying to make something similar in android. I'm using a gridView which is somewhat similar to the UICollectionView in iOS. But I simply don't understand why I can't set a height for the gridView.
What I want to achieve is to set a specific keyboard height, like the same as system keyboard, so only 8-10 images appear and then I can scroll through the others. Adding paging and horizontal scrolling would be a bonus  and a final step.

Here is my XML file for the keyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/imageGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My InputServiceManagers onCreateInputView:

```
 public View onCreateInputView() {

        keyboardView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard,null);

        List<Integer> imageArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20;i++){
            try {
                Class res = R.drawable.class;
                String imageName = "sticker" + String.valueOf(i);
                Field field = res.getField(imageName);
                int drawableID = field.getInt(null);
                imageArray.add(drawableID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyTag","Failure to get drawable id.",e);
            }
        }

        imageGrid = (GridView) keyboardView.findViewById(R.id.imageGridView);
        imageGrid.setNumColumns(4);
        ImageGridAdapter adapter = new ImageGridAdapter(this);
        adapter.imageArray = imageArray;
        imageGrid.setAdapter(adapter);


        return keyboardView;

    }
```

GridViewAdapter:

```
public class ImageGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    public List<Integer> imageArray;

    public ImageGridAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return imageArray.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120, 120));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(imageArray.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }


}
```

This is how the end product should look like:
[image]

And this is how it looks now:
[image]

Comment: I suspect your problem in part of your code that you didn't show.  If I inflate your layout file, I get a height of 240dp but at the top of the display.  Look at the parent of keyboard.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used your code and it's working fine, the stickers are showing in the keyboard area with a scrollbar. By the way I'm working on a similar project right now, I think we can help each other if you want.

[image: Androi Emoji Keyboard]

Comment: Thanks, I've found the solution! :)

Comment: Email me.: orbanbalazs.xyz@icloud.com

Comment: Hi @user3621033, I'm developing a project like yours, can you share with me your code? I'm having errors on my code. Thanks